# File read error does not read what is inside the .txt file

Tags: c++

Write a program for a meteorologist that calculates the wind chill factor and cloud base altitude for the inputs temperature in Fahrenheit, wind speed in mph, and the dew point in Fahrenheit.

4 functions

1. one for getting input

- tmeperature in farenheight
- wind speed in mph
- dew point in fahrenhiet

2. compute the wind chill
   must be at or below 50 degrees fahrenheit
3. compute the cloud base
4. one for the output

4 more functions

1. one for opening the files with file failure conditions *** this is where the problem lies using ***
2. one to compute the wind chill
3. one to compute the cloud base
4. one for the output consider other functions as you see fit

```cpp
    #include <iostream>

    #include <cmath>

    #include <math.h>

    #include <fstream>


    using namespace std;
    
    //function prototypes
    //void getUserInput(double& temp, double& wind_speed, double& dew_point);

    //calculate the wind chill 
    void calculateWindChill(double& temp, double& wind_speed, double& wc);

    //calculate  cloud base 
    void calculateCloudBase(double& temp, double& dew_point, double& cb);

    // show cases the data on the program that was calculated
    void dataOutPut(double wc, double cb);

    //opens file for data scan
    void fileopn(double& temp, double& wind_speed, double& dew_point);

    int main()
    {
    //intializing variables
    double temp = 0, wind_speed = 0, dew_point = 0, wc = 0, cb = 0;
    bool valid = false;
    do
    {

        fileopn( temp,  wind_speed,  dew_point);
        // validates if temp is greater than 50 F and wind chill must be greater than 3.0 mphs
        if (temp > 50 || wind_speed < 3.0)
        {
            cout << "error temperature mus be less than 50 degrees and wind speed must be above 3.0         mphs" << endl;
        }
    } while (temp > 50 || wind_speed < 3.0);

    calculateWindChill(temp, wind_speed, wc);
    calculateCloudBase(temp, dew_point, cb);
    dataOutPut(wc, cb);
    return 0;
    }

    //get inputs from the user 

    void dataOutPut(double wc, double cb)
    {
        cout << " the wind chill is :" << wc << endl;

        cout << "the cloud base is : " << cb << endl;
    }

    //calculates windChill

    void calculateWindChill(double& temp, double& wind_speed, double& wc)
    {

        wc = 35.74 + (0.6215 * temp) - (35.37 * pow(wind_speed, 0.16)) + (0.4275 * temp *    pow(wind_speed, 0.16));


     }
     //calculate Cloudbase

     void calculateCloudBase(double& temp, double& dew_point, double& cb)
     {
        double temp_spread = temp - dew_point;
        cb = temp_spread / (4.4 * 1000);  // caclulates cloudbase (formula)
     }

     //opens file
     void fileopn(double& temp, double& wind_speed, double& dew_point)
     {
        ifstream inputFile;
        string filename;
        double number;
        //get filename from user
        cout << "Enter file name " << endl;
        cin >> filename;



        
        cout << inputFile.is_open();
        if (inputFile)
        {

            while (inputFile >> number)
            {
            cout << number << endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error opening the file . \n";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Instead of dumping the homework question you should've provided details of what exactly is wrong and at which lines of code it happened

Comment: I expect the file is in the wrong folder or the user named it incorrectly.

Comment: If your problem is about opening the file there is no reason at all to post the assignment requirements. Remember the purpose of your question is to help future readers solve 1 problem you have identified in your code perhaps years from now.

Comment: Write code a few lines at a time before compiling and testing. This allows you to find errors early so they don't build up. It's relatively easy to find and fix one error in 3-5 lines of code, but a whole 'nother matter to find 10 problems in 30-50 lines of code.

Comment: In order for homework questions to be [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." Since you haven't done that, this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You ask for the filename but you don't actually open the file:

```
 inputFile.open (filename, std::ifstream::in);
```

This might help.